# Facebook Graph Api: Unable to get latest post for keywords

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can anyone help me, When I request using link

https://graph.facebook.com/search?&limit=2&until=now&q=hi&type=post&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAIScEzst3h5VpV8pKZA7di2ZC3czxr5

Note: I am not giving valid token for security reason.

I always get the result for 27 Nov 2012, while I tried to search for latest post. Am I missing something? Please help.
Thanks in Advance.
RESULT I get:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "730221920_10151138508071921",
         "from": {
            "name": "Pinky Saowichit",
            "id": "730221920"
         },
         "message": "\u0e2d\u0e32\u0e17\u0e34\u0e15\u0e22\u0e4c\u0e19\u0e35\u0e49\u0e2d\u0e32\u0e08\u0e44\u0e21\u0e48\u0e44\u0e14\u0e49\u0e2d\u0e2d\u0e31\u0e19\u0e1a\u0e48\u0e2d\u0e22\u0e46 \u0e19\u0e30\u0e04\u0e30 \u0e41\u0e1f\u0e19\u0e04\u0e25\u0e31\u0e1a \u0e43\u0e2b\u0e49\u0e23\u0e39\u0e49\u0e27\u0e48\u0e48\u0e32\u0e04\u0e34\u0e14\u0e16\u0e36\u0e07\u0e19\u0e30\u0e04\u0e30 \u0e41\u0e15\u0e48\u0e15\u0e2d\u0e19\u0e19\u0e35\u0e49\u0e40\u0e23\u0e32\u0e01\u0e33\u0e25\u0e31\u0e07\u0e04\u0e34\u0e14\u0e16\u0e36\u0e07\u0e04\u0e38\u0e13 \u0e04\u0e32\u0e19\u0e18\u0e35\u0e41\u0e25\u0e30\u0e40\u0e17\u0e40\u0e23\u0e0b\u0e48\u0e32\u0e2d\u0e22\u0e48\u0e32\u0e07\u0e21\u0e32\u0e01\u0e46 \u0e2b\u0e38 \u0e2b\u0e38",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "status",
         "status_type": "mobile_status_update",
         "created_time": "2012-11-27T03:12:32+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-11-27T07:44:54+0000",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Weniefredo Laud",
                  "id": "100004751890183"
               },
               {
                  "name": "\u0e1e\u0e23\u0e15 \u0e1c\u0e25\u0e14\u0e35",
                  "id": "100001056963372"
               },
               {
                  "name": "\u0e08\u0e23\u0e34\u0e0d\u0e32 \u0e25\u0e2d\u0e27",
                  "id": "100000046347271"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Noolek Tikamborn",
                  "id": "100003048464258"
               }
            ],
            "count": 6
         }
      },
      {
         "id": "100003971930240_283727615063091",
         "from": {
            "name": "Mariana Salcedo",
            "id": "100003971930240"
         },
         "story": "Mariana Salcedo shared a link.",
         "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQASxQms6c0xFkdO&w=90&h=90&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fask.fm\u00252Fimages\u00252F50x50.gif",
         "link": "http://ask.fm/marianasalcedo/answer/15735435637",
         "name": "CRUSH hi",
         "caption": "jajajajaja que enfadosa erees!",
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yN/x/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "link",
         "status_type": "shared_story",
         "application": {
            "name": "Ask.fm",
            "id": "129215213762342"
         },
         "created_time": "2012-11-27T03:11:38+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-11-27T03:11:38+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=hi&limit=2&type=post&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAIScEzst3h5VpV8pKZA7di2ZC3czxr5ANnvKPPc1wqYJJZAANd9PI0NKLX5Xk5ReRX3T01iim8BoJp6r16itU8vPxRP&since=1353985952&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=hi&limit=2&type=post&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAIScEzst3h5VpV8pKZA7di2ZC3czxr5ANnvKPPc1wqYJJZAANd9PI0NKLX5Xk5ReRX3T01iim8Bo&until=1353985897"
   }
}
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/427439360643880